# Declaring properties to class, fields and prime numbers

Tags: c#, class, object, field, primes

I'm new to classes in C# and I'm learning c# online and I have a problem on next exercise:

Write a class TestForNumbers, which has two properties SetNumber and SetField and they allow to add a integer and one field of numbers to the class.

My question, how to set the properties of a class? And let them allow that?

So, these values are saved in a temporary variables, tmpNumber and tmpField.

How can you save a field of numbers in one variable??

Then the class has one more method NumberOfRelativelyPrime - which has no parameters and returns an integer which shows the amount of the numbers in the field which are relatively prime with the number followed by the properties of the SetNumber class.

Other than the class, create an object from the class TestForNumbers and add test values for number=3 and field={2,3,4,6,8,10,13}. Then call the method NumberOfRelativelyPrime and the result of calling the class to be added in the variable RelativelyPrime.

NOTES:
Two numbers are relatively prime if their greatest common divisor is 1. Example numbers are: 2 and 3, 5 and 7, 4 and 11.

Instructions:
If we take the properties of SetNumber and SetField of the object in the class TestForNumbers, and followed by their values 3 and {2,3,4,6,8,10,13} then the method NumberOfRelativelyPrime should return value 5, because the number 3 is relatively prime with the elements of the field {2,3,4,6,8,10,13}. GCD(3,3)=3 which is bigger than 1. GCD(3,6) = 3, bigger than 1, which is why the elements 3 and 6 are not relatively prime with the number 3.

"The optimization of the code is unimportant, it's enough if the exercise returns the correct value." (by the exercise itself)

Yes, I haven't done much because I'm pretty stuck on it... my code is below and will be updated as I get new information and learn something to do.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class TestForNumbers
    {
        public string SetNumber
        {
            get;
            set
            {
                //int tmpNumber = SetNumber();
            }
        }

        public int NumberOfRelativelyPrime
        {

        }

        public string SetField
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you simplify this to a single questions? There are a dozen topics in this that you appear to be asking for help with.

Comment: I updated the code.. am I on the right track? I'd like to ask the following.. how can I make a field property of multiple numbers? and how to create an object from a class?

Comment: are you after the algorithm or youre asking for something code related? its very unclear what your question actually is

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the terminology is what is not being understood. This is a small example class to demonstrate the differences between fields and properties, and how to set a property. Take a look at this and see if it helps you to reform your question.

```
    class TestForNumbers
    {
        private string _ThisIsAField; // a plain old variable at the class level is a field.

        public string ThisIsAnAutomaticProperty { get; set; } //this is a typing shortcut, you dont need a backing field.

        private string _ThisIsAPropertyBackingField; //another field, but this value is exposed via the property

        public string ThisIsAProperty
        {
            get { return _ThisIsAPropertyBackingField; }
            set { _ThisIsAPropertyBackingField = value; } //omit this line if you dont want callers to set the value.
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var tfn = new TestForNumbers();
            tfn.ThisIsAProperty = "new Value";
            tfn.ThisIsAnAutomaticProperty = "Another new value";
            //tfn._ThisIsAField = "Doesnt Work";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about properties of a class? How do you set them? (SetNumber, SetField)

Comment: ThisIsAProperty and ThisIsAnAutomaticProperty ARE properties of the class. The statements in static void Main are setting values into them.

Comment: Very good.. I tried some code, but I'm really stuck with the creation of object and the field of multiple numbers.